# How to know the command of Siri about HomeKiit in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, siri, homekit, ios-homekit

I am new to HomeKit , and I got a demo board which it can work with iPhone.

When I turn on the demo borad , I can see the **Accessories** in **`Setting -> WiFi`**. I click the **Accessories** and add the **Accessories** to the WiFi Network. The **Accessories** and the **iPhone** are in the same WiFi Network.

I turn on Siri and say "Turn On the Light" , the LED on the demo board will turn on.

But it should has other command to control the light for adjust light levels up or down.

**How do I know the all command of Siri about HomeKit in iOS ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Homekit has its central database for managing homes and its features.
Database is shared with all homekit enabled apps install in iOS device.
And also by siri.

So siri will have access to names you have given to Home, accessory, trigger, scene etc.

Now you can use the names you have given and default characteristic of any accessory to execute by siri.
like "Siri, turn **on** the **desk lamp** in the **Main hall**"

For the above command **on** is a value of the characteristic.

**desk lamp** is an accessory.

**Main hall** is name of room.
In this command home name is not provided so siri will consider it for primary home.

You can create commands by your own.
Below are few the examples.

"Siri, set library temperature in My Home to 72"

Here **library** is name of **Room**

**My Home** is name of **Home**

**temperature** is characteristic which is apple definded siri keyword.

**72** is Value of characteristic.

You can refer to apple documentation for more detail.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HomeKit/Reference/HomeKit_Framework/